# Replacing Character using Regular Expression in java

Tags: java, regex

I have a `String` where a substring with third bracket can contain like that

```
String str = "merSampleFactoryList[0].tfSendDate.fields[0].durationField.supported";
```

I want to replace all `[0]`,`[1]`,`[2]`...... with "`[]`" . I know i can do it using regular expression but don't know how to do that.

Comment: What have you tried? It's a pretty simple implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**String::replaceAll**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) with regex `\[.*?\]`:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\[.*?\\]", "[]")
```

**Output**

```
merSampleFactoryList[].tfSendDate.fields[].durationField.supported
```

## regex demo

---

**Note**

In case you want to replace only the bracket which contains integers then you can use `\[\d+\]` instead.

---

Or like @Dukeling mention in comment you can use `\[[^]]*\]` instead of `\[.*?\]`

## regex demo 2

Comment: `[^]]*` is probably better than `.*?`.

Comment: Thank you @Dukeling can i know the difference this is new for me but it work

Comment: @Dukeling `]` is a metacharacter so I think it should be escaped: `[^\]]*`

Comment: @YCF_L `[abc]` is a character class, in this case meaning "a or b or c exactly once". `^` is the exclusion, so for example `[^ab]` means "any character which is not a and not b, exactly once". `[^\]]*` means "sequence of 0 or more characters which are not `]`". See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html for more info.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak `]` as the first character in a character class (i.e. directly following `[` or `[^`) doesn't need to be escaped (since the alternative would imply an empty character class, which doesn't make much sense, although it may very well depend on the tool or language used). Although I can see the argument for escaping it just for clarity.

Comment: you can check my answer now @Dukeling